# Find the area between $y=\frac{-1}{6\sin x}+3$ and $y=\frac{1}{6\sin x}+3$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, area

I can't seem to find the area bounded by the s-curves. Help?

Comment: yup i meant that

Comment: Is that a problem in the book or you just made it by yourself?

Comment: I graphed it on an application but I can't get its area

Comment: Of course, you can't find the area since the graphs don't have intersection?.

Comment: The intersection is x=(pi)(n)?

Comment: No. The value of $\sin x$ is uniquely determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the area bounded by the curves since they do not intersect for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. See the graphs I've plotted below on [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ehcfvvccnv):

[image]

Comment: I'm a user of desmos also. But I cant do it by  pasting the commands. How did you do that.

Comment: Are you using the Print Screen Command?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Yes, I used "Print Screen Command". Good question.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it now.

Comment: Success, thanks for your help. I know how do it now. (+1)